# JS Loop not looping until I comment out my switch method

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, switch-statement

Been stuck on a problem for a few hours now where my for loop won't loop (only does 1 iteration).

The following is my code:

```
function getScore(summonerId) {

$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v2.2/matchhistory/' + summonerId + '/?queueType=NORMAL_5x5_BLIND,NORMAL_5x5_DRAFT,RANKED_SOLO_5x5,RANKED_PREMADE_5x5,NORMAL_5x5_DRAFT,RANKED_TEAM_5x5&beginIndex=0&endIndex=9&api_key=***',
    success: function (data, state) {

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){ // THIS IS THE LOOP THAT WON'T WORK.
            console.log(i);
            console.log(state);
            //v1.1.0

            if (data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.firstBloodKill == true){
                firstBloodArray[i] = 1;
            }else{
                firstBloodArray[i] = 0;
            }

            if (data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.firstTowerKill == true){
                firstTowerArray[i] = 1;
            }else{
                firstTowerArray[i] = 0;
            }

            if (data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.firstTowerKill == true){
                firstInhibitorArray[i] = 1;
            }else{
                firstInhibitorArray[i] = 0;
            }

            damageDealtArray[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.totalDamageDealt;
            healingDealtArray[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.totalHeal;
            damageTakenArray[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.totalDamageTaken;
            inhibitorArray[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.inhibitorKills;
            towerArray[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.towerKills;

            //timeline arrays

            tl_arr_cspm_zero_ten[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.creepsPerMinDeltas.zeroToTen;
            tl_arr_cspm_ten_twenty[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.creepsPerMinDeltas.tenToTwenty;

            if(data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.creepsPerMinDeltas.twentyToThirty != undefined) {
                tl_arr_cspm_twenty_thirty[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.creepsPerMinDeltas.twentyToThirty;
            }else{
                tl_arr_cspm_twenty_thirty[i] = 0
            }

            if(data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.creepsPerMinDeltas.thirtyToEnd != undefined) {
                tl_arr_cspm_thirty_end[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.creepsPerMinDeltas.thirtyToEnd;
            }else{
                tl_arr_cspm_thirty_end[i] = 0
            }

            tl_arr_xppm_zero_ten[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.xpPerMinDeltas.zeroToTen;
            tl_arr_xppm_ten_twenty[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.xpPerMinDeltas.tenToTwenty;

            if(data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.xpPerMinDeltas.twentyToThirty != undefined) {
                tl_arr_xppm_twenty_thirty[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.xpPerMinDeltas.twentyToThirty;
            }else{
                tl_arr_xppm_twenty_thirty[i] = 0;
            }

            if(data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.xpPerMinDeltas.thirtyToEnd != undefined){
                tl_arr_xppm_thirty_end[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.xpPerMinDeltas.thirtyToEnd;
            }else{
                tl_arr_xppm_thirty_end[i] = 0;
            }


            tl_arr_gpm_zero_ten[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.goldPerMinDeltas.zeroToTen;
            tl_arr_gpm_ten_twenty[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.goldPerMinDeltas.tenToTwenty;

            if(data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.goldPerMinDeltas.twentyToThirty != undefined){
                tl_arr_gpm_twenty_thirty[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.goldPerMinDeltas.twentyToThirty;
            }else{
                tl_arr_gpm_twenty_thirty[i] = 0;
            }

            if(data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.goldPerMinDeltas.thirtyToEnd != undefined){
                tl_arr_gpm_thirty_end[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.goldPerMinDeltas.thirtyToEnd;
            }else{
                tl_arr_gpm_thirty_end[i] = 0;
            }


            //v1.0.2

            csArray[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.minionsKilled;
            assistArray[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.assists;
            killArray[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.kills;
            gameTimeArray[i] = data.matches[i].matchDuration;
            championArray[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].championId;
            deathArray[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.deaths;
            jungleCSArray[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.neutralMinionsKilledTeamJungle;
            counterJungleCSArray[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.neutralMinionsKilledEnemyJungle;
            roleArray[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.role;
            laneArray[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.lane;
            crowdControlArray[i] = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.totalTimeCrowdControlDealt;

            switch (roleArray[i]) {
                case "DUO":
                case "SOLO":
                    //assumes top lane duo player or solo mid or solo top
                    calculateHmc(1.33, 1, 0.5, 0.06, 0.11, 0.17, 5, 0.5, 4, 0.5, 0.16, 0.65, 2, 1.25, 3, 1.5, 1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3,  i);
                    break;
                case "DUO_CARRY":
                    //assumes bot lane adc
                    calculateHmc(1.33, 1, 0.5, 0.06, 0.11, 0.17, 5, 0.5, 4, 0.5, 0.16, 0.65, 2, 1.25, 3, 2, 1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, i);
                    break;
                case "DUO_SUPPORT":
                    //assumes bot lane support
                    calculateHmc(1.33, 1, 0.75, 0.06, 0.11, 0.17, 0.5, 5, 4, 0.5, 0.16, 0.65, 2, 1.25, 0.25, 3.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, i);
                    break;
                case "NONE":
                    //assumes jungle, check lane
                    calculateHmc(1.33, 1, 0.5, 0.06, 0.11, 0.17, 2, 2.5, 4, 0.5, 0.16, 0.65, 2, 1.25, 1.5, 1.5, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, i);
                    break;
            }
        }


    }
});
```

If I comment the switch out, the loop works.

I have tried re-writing the loop to make sure it wasnt a syntax error in my loop declaration but that's not the case.

I need the loop to loop 10 times and call the calculateHmc function 10 times, but it's only doing it once.

As soon as switch (roleArray[i]) is commented out, the loop works, but obviously it doesn't call teh function.

Any ideas why this would happen?

Comment: Are you checking errors in console? What does `calculateHmc()` do?

Comment: Yes sir and I have no errors when I have the switch in, or out.

Comment: where is that i in the loop coming from? You're not defining it with var so it is probably being created as a global variable that is overwritten by a call to some other function that also uses i.

try in the for loop for (var i=0; i<10; i++)  (include the var before i to make sure it is not defined as global)

Comment: Wow, markus, you are a genuis..

I did NOT know that!

Thanks so much, problem fixed!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you move your switch block to its own function and call it like that (instead of directly in your loop)? On a side note, id recommend doing something similar with all your if blocks in order to make your code more clear/maintainable

Comment: Your real problem is your messy code, which is simply unmaintainable. There's more to coding than "does it work?"—code should look nice (*pretty*) and be easy to understand. As they say, DRY & KISS.

Comment: I'm still a noob, so I do my best @royhowie !

Comment: @Vranvs a good rule of thumb is try to keep your functions short—it isn't a hard and fast rule, but ~25 lines max. In addition, functions should do only *one* thing (this lets you reuse code more easily).

Comment: You should accept one of the answers that post this solution for future reference. Also I would suggest going through some of the videos of Douglas Crockford who does a good job of emphasizing the fundamentals and quirks of javascript.

Comment: Thanks guys. @MárKüsBaptiste yes- i accepted one, I just had to wait a few minutes.

Comment: You really should learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. That will help a lot with these sorts of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to hazard a guess that the global variable `i` you are using in your `for` statement is getting trounced by `calculateHMC()` leading to the premature termination of your `for` loop.

In any case, change the `for` statement to use a local variable rather than an implicit global:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

And, inspect `calculateHMC()` for a similar issue.  Even if that is not the only issue in your code, it IS an issue that should be fixed.

---

In fact, if you run your code in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), it will point all of these out to you as errors which is, of course, one of the very reasons for using strict mode so you can't accidentally make these kinds of errors.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot help noticing that `i` is not declared as a local variable, and is therefore a global variable.  Perhaps `calculateHmc()` has the same error and is advancing the value of `i` past 9.

Declare `var i` in both functions and see if that fixes it.  Even if it doesn't, you are better off.